# Can not get music to play on my music player app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I am trying to make a music player app for my school project.

When I run the app everything thing works, except for the fact that when I click on a song it does not play.

Please help me with a detailed explanation so i can fix the app.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var songs:[String] = []
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTabelView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return songs.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = songs[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        do
        {
            if let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[indexPath.row], ofType: ".mp3") {
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath) as URL)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }



    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        gettingSongName()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func gettingSongName()  // Get the names of all the songs
    {
         let folderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!)

        do
        {
            let songPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles) // Axcess all of the song files

            for song in songPath
            {
                var mySong = song.absoluteString


                if mySong.contains(".mp3")
                {
                    let findString = mySong.components(separatedBy: "/")
                    mySong = (findString[findString.count-1])
                    mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ")
                    mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: ".mp3", with: " ")
                    songs.append(mySong)

                }
            }

            myTabelView.reloadData()
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just initializing the audioPlayer without asking it to play, try adding this in your didSelectRow do block after the after the audioPlayer init

```
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
audioPlayer.play()
audioPlayer.delegate = self
```